# How to dynamically reference a row number from a formula E{(A2+A4)} for example Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Hoping this is a simple one.

Im looking to do a simple addition of 2 values to complete a cell selection in Google Sheets.

So for example `E({A2+A4})` with `A2=10` and `A4=5` the selected value returned would be from cell E15?

Answer (score 2):

Ive actually found it.

=INDIRECT("E"&(A2+A4))